# Send byte[254] is sent in what form

Tags: c#, byte, ascii

I have this code in c# and it works perfectly, sending the correct numbers to a relay to turn on/off the relays. I am trying to use an Arduino program and micro controller to control the relay and am struggling to get any response out of the relay. One of the options I am checking is to see what format this program is sending the bytes in (binary, ascii character codes, ascii characters, etc.) to try to mimic this in the other program.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.IO.Ports;
 using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("hello world");
        LightRelayBoard lrb = new LightRelayBoard("COM1");
        lrb.WorkspaceLight(4);
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        lrb.Query();

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        lrb.WorkspaceLight(0);
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        lrb.Query();

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class LightRelayBoard
{
    SerialPort sp;
    byte[] relay1Off = new byte[2];
    byte[] relay2Off = new byte[2];
    byte[] relay3Off = new byte[2];
    byte[] relay4Off = new byte[2];
    byte[] relay1On = new byte[2];
    byte[] relay2On = new byte[2];
    byte[] relay3On = new byte[2];
    byte[] relay4On = new byte[2];
    byte[] relay1query = new byte[2];

    int currentState = 0;



    public LightRelayBoard(string portName) // constructor
    {
        relay1Off[0] = (byte)254;
        relay1Off[1] = 0;
        relay2Off[0] = (byte)254;
        relay2Off[1] = 1;
        relay3Off[0] = (byte)254;
        relay3Off[1] = 2;
        relay4Off[0] = (byte)254;
        relay4Off[1] = 3;
        relay1On[0] = (byte)254;
        relay1On[1] = (byte)8;
        relay2On[0] = (byte)254;
        relay2On[1] = (byte)9;
        relay3On[0] = (byte)254;
        relay3On[1] = (byte)10;
        relay4On[0] = (byte)254;
        relay4On[1] = (byte)11;
        relay1query[0] = (byte)254;
        relay1query[1] = (byte)16;

        sp = new SerialPort(portName, 9600);

        sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);



        try { sp.Open(); }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't open light relay board: port ({0})", portName);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            WorkspaceLight(i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            WorkspaceLight(i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }


    }

    public void WorkspaceLight(int command)
    {
        if (command > 4)
            command = 4;
        else if (command < 0)
            command = 0;

        if (command > currentState)
        {
            for (int i = (currentState + 1); i <= command; i++)
            {
                executeRelay(i, true); //turn on ith relay
                //Console.WriteLine("{0} on", i);
            }
            currentState = command;
        }
        else if (command < currentState)
        {
            for (int i = currentState; i > command; i--)
            {
                executeRelay(i, false); //turn on ith relay// turn off ith relay
                //Console.WriteLine("{0} off", i);
            }

            currentState = command;
        }

        return;
    }

    public void Query()
    {
        if (sp.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                sp.Write(relay1query, 0, 2);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private void executeRelay(int ch, bool dir)
    {
        byte[] send = relay1Off;

        if (ch == 1 && dir == true)
            send = relay1On;
        else if (ch == 1 && dir == false)
            send = relay1Off;
        else if (ch == 2 && dir == true)
            send = relay2On;
        else if (ch == 2 && dir == false)
            send = relay2Off;
        else if (ch == 3 && dir == true)
            send = relay3On;
        else if (ch == 3 && dir == false)
            send = relay3Off;
        else if (ch == 4 && dir == true)
            send = relay4On;
        else if (ch == 4 && dir == false)
            send = relay4Off;

        if (sp.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                sp.Write(send, 0, 2);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp2 = (SerialPort)sender;
        int numBytes = sp2.BytesToRead;
        byte[] sp2buffer = new byte[numBytes];
        sp2.Read(sp2buffer, 0, sp2.BytesToRead);

        Console.WriteLine("DATA from sp: {0}", sp2buffer[0].ToString()); 
    }
}
```

Here is the Arduino code:

```
    int ledPin = 13;
    unsigned char a = B11111110;
    unsigned char b = B00001000;
    void setup()
    {
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    // serial communication
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial2.begin(9600); //serial comms with relay board
    }
    void loop()

{
if(Serial.available()>0){ //available means it is receiving data
  Serial2.print(a);
 Serial.println(a); //see what Serial is printing on the screen
 Serial2.print(b);
Serial.print(b);
}
if(Serial2.available()>0){ //check if serial 2 is recieving data 

  Serial.write("data");
      }
  else{
      Serial.print("no data");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary is just a way to represent numbers.  ASCII characters and character codes are going to have the integer value as bytes.

There is no "format" in your case.  You are setting the individual bytes directly.  Maybe the question is why your other program isn't producing the same results?

Comment: That is the question, I was trying to approach it from a different direction...so it's just sending the byte (ie 254 is sent as '254' not as binary).

Comment: @user1529286 So are you actually sending 3 bytes? '2', '5', and '4'?  What other language are you using?

Comment: I am trying to use Arduino instead. When I use it, and have what it is sending print to the screen, it shows either the ASCii character or it prints out each indiv number ('2' then'5' then '4') not just '254' as one byte. I've tried print, write, using int, char, unsigned char, bin, byte, and there never is a reaction with the relay.

Comment: I gotcha.  Well without seeing the code you're using for the Arduino, there's not much I can tell you.

Comment: I've added the Arduino code to the bottom of the post. This is just one of the ways I have tried. The other possibility I am seeing online is that I may need a transistor between the Arduino and the relay due to high amps needed for the relay (R410Pro). Is this true if the relay has its own power source?

Comment: I don't know anything about the relay board your using, but likely the high amperage you're seeing isn't what's required to switch it, so you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

A [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  can hold unsigned values from 0 to 255. It has no "format" associated with it other than what *you* interpret it to be.